# PHP tell how many users logged in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some a MYSQL db with a DATETIME field that updates itself every minute while a user is logged in via AJAX. This works perfectly. However I am trying to get a count of how many logged in users there are and it is not working

```
$table = 'mytable';
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE lidtm > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $num;
```

theoretically this should tell me how many users are logged in, because each users 'lidtm' field updates every minute while they are logged in, so if the DATE_SUB function counts the rows in which the lidtm field is > that now() - 1 minute, it should tell me all users that have been updated by my ajax within the last minute.

but for some reason it always returns all rows.

what am I missing. I need a count of how many rows the 'lidtm' field is within the last minute.

Comment: Calling `DATE(now())` casts it to a date, and thus, the nearest 24 hours. Just drop the `DATE()` bit and pass `now()` by itself.

Comment: @AlexHowansky you should post that as answer.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE lidtm > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)

Comment: just curious : why would you not keep a boolean login flag instead?

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti Because HTTP is stateless and you'd never know when to set it to false.

Comment: timestamps are the only way to accurately tell if an HTTP page is accessed or not

Comment: can you update your post to include the db schema and representative values? @user3005775 because I for one am unable to reproduce. You also mention ajax but there's no code to support the question, should that be a factor here. Or how your db gets updated.

Comment: fixed it, now it is working properly, I think the problem was that I had 2 queries in the script, and both were echoing the same variable. So I don't think the 2nd query had a chance to complete before the variable was echoed. So I changed the variable names for the 2nd query, and now it returns the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping `now()` with `date()` casts it to a date, i.e., without a time:

```
select date(now());
+-------------+
| date(now()) |
+-------------+
| 2017-05-16  |
+-------------
```

If you want to measure minutes, you need the time:

```
select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-05-16 13:56:00 |
+---------------------+
```

So just take out the call to `date()`, and use:

```
select date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute);
+------------------------------------+
| date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) |
+------------------------------------+
| 2017-05-16 13:56:17                |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: currently one user logged in, timestamp is 2017-05-16 19:59:36, current time is 2017-05-16 20:01:44, clearly past the 1 minute time frame since I had the user log out

Comment: @user3005775 what Alex posted should have worked since it worked for me. Maybe there's something in your ajax that you didn't post causing this. Run `select date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute);` from within phpmyadmin to see what that returns. If it failed, then your column may not be the right type,  and/or something else is failing you.

Comment: did within phpmyadmin, and it still returns 1 row even though the timestamp is now 30 minutes old. The field is DATETIME type so not sure if that is mattering